# MySQL has many through

Tags: has-many-through

1- Users may have many classrooms
2- Classrooms may have many users
3- Users may have many payments in their classrooms

how can I get a classroom payments through its users with SQL?

how can I get sum of the payments of a user per classroom?

```
-- Payments Table: --
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| amount     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

-- Users Table: --
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

-- Classrooms Table: --
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

-- Classroom_User Table: --
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| classroom_id| int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: i've tried nothing :D

Comment: will you be able to use Stack when doing the exam? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing, I'd say:

```
SELECT p.amount, u.name, c.name
FROM payments p, users u, classrooms c, classroom_user ct
WHERE   ct.user_id = u.id
    AND ct.classroom_id = c.id
    AND u.id = p.user_id
```

However: it's not clear what your tables are about. For instance: one record in the payments table can result in multiple records in the result set, namely when there are multiple records in the classroom_user table for the same user.

Something in your database design *feels* wrong, but it's hard to tell what's wrong without more info.

Suppose that you want to get the payments for each classroom. In that case, your database design is wrong because you only know the amount each user paid in total, not the amount the user paid per classroom.

The payments table should look like this:

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| classroom_user_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| amount            | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In that case, you'd have:

```
SELECT c.name, u.name, p.amount
FROM payments p, users u, classrooms c, classroom_user ct
WHERE   p.classroom_user_id = ct.id
    AND ct.classroom_id = c.id
    AND ct.user_id = u.id
```

Or, if you want to get the total amount per classroom:

```
SELECT c.name, SUM(p.amount)
FROM payments p, classrooms c, classroom_user ct
WHERE   p.classroom_user_id = ct.id
    AND ct.classroom_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Note that I didn't test this. I don't have your database.

Comment: The comments are not the place to add explanations. Please update the question. And while you're at it, update the title. I cleaned up the layout of your question, but I didn't know how to correct the title, because in its current state, your title doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Aha, now I see the explanation. The database design is wrong. That makes your question unanswerable. Where it says `user_id` in the Payments table, it should actually say `classroom_user_id`.

Comment: so whats your suggestion for database design?

Comment: so the main question is not answered yet, how can i get a user payments in a classroom? or a classroom payments?

Comment: thanks for your anwers, i'll go for a test ;)

Comment: Be quick because you already have 3 down votes and 4 votes to close the question (one more and your question is refused).

Comment: Yes, its working like a charm :D

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, what are down votes?

Comment: Do the tour and you'll know: http://stackoverflow.com/tour (the idea is to gain reputation points. You win points when you ask good questions and provide good answers. You lose points when you ask bad questions and provide bad answers. The higher your reputation, the higher your credibility.

Comment: I've updated the question, ca any one please tell me how to get sum of the payments of a user per classroom?

Comment: No one is reading a closed question, so please create a new one.